# Jar working : through JNLP not working

Tags: java, jnlp

I have created a java SE application that uses the mysql database using mysql java connector.I have hosted the apache and mysql server on ubuntu.

I have my .jar file on the apache server and also the jnlp,

When I simply download the jar file and run it, it seems to work, but, when I am trying to use it through jnlp the first view comes up then when I enter my username and password  and click the login button it just stops there

Here is my JNLP file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://servername:80/" href="" >
    <information>
        <title>MyProject</title>
        <vendor>abd</vendor>
        <icon href="icon_1.jpg"/>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+" href=
           "http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="MyJar.jar" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc
         main-class="" >
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Please let me know what it the error.
On the server I have 80 8080 and 3306 ports as public ports.

as I said I can update the database using the jarfile that I downloaded from the server but when I try to run the file through JNLP I freezes.

I saw the exception in java console it says

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:286)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at MyProject.database.connect(database.java:27)

Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.encoding" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)

I cant figure out what the problem is? do I need some port open for JNLP or anything.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things that come to mind:

1. You need to sign the jar for javawebstart to allow access to sockets.
2. You are obviously trying to connect to a mysql DB, it is unclear from your description where this db is and if connection to the host is allowed.
3. did you bundle the mydql driver in your jar ? or is it referenced somehow ?

Comment: How do I sign the jar for javawebstart and allow access to sockets.
As I said I already can do the database operation by just downloading the jar file, but, I do not know how to sign the jar file to be used by javawebstart and allow access to sockets am fairly new to JNLP and JWS.


My DB is also on the remote machine but the database port 3306 has public access with grant privileges from all ips

yes I did bundle mysql driver in the jar

Comment: could you guide me on the signing issue point me in some direction?? I will really appreciate it

THanks

Comment: 500 chars is not enough to give you a tutorial, here are a few pointers: cheap certs - http://codesigning.ksoftware.net/  as far as jar signing, just check google search.

Comment: +1 for *"500 chars is not enough to give you a tutorial"* (as well as the answer).

Comment: @Olivier Refalo I used the jar signer utility to sign the jar file and then used that jar file .. but it still gives me the same error also the signing tutorial did not mention anything about buying certificates. what am I doing wrong i see the dsa and sf files tooo in the signed jar ... but it still doesn't work thanks for your responses i really appreciate it

Comment: Once signed, webstart should prompt you when you run the application. It should show details about the cert and allow to run or reject the app.

Comment: nope that doesnt happen ... I dont know what you mean by signing I followed this tutorial http://ezzatron.com/2009/09/29/automatically-signing-jar-files-in-netbeans/ created a keystore and signed on cmd prompt using jar sign and as i said i saw the dsa and sf files but the error still persists am I doing something wrong?

Comment: in the link they create a self signed certificate to sign the jar. There is no way Webstart serves this jar without displaying a warning message. -> clear your caches, maybe change the version number in the jnlp to make sure the plugin picks a new version. Not sure where webstart stores its cache.

Answer (score 1):

> do I need some port open for JNLP or anything.

Only if you've configured JNLP to use a non-standard port.

It is hard to remotely diagnose what is going on here.  You probably need to figure out at what point the freeze is occurring.  Is it during the JNLP application download phase?  While the JVM is loading your classes?  During application initialization?  In the last case, can you identify where the application is freezing; e.g. by taking a thread dump?

---

The `ExceptionInInitializerError` exception is a good start.  Somewhere in that stack trace there should be another "cause" exception that should give you a big clue as to what the real problem is.

(My guess is that some firewall somewhere is blocking access on port 3360.  Can you connect to the database from the client machine using the command line SQL tool, or is that blocked too?

On second thoughts, the signing issue is a more plausible explanation, especially if the SQL tool works.)

---

There are many tutorials on the web on how to sign a JAR file.  For example:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html

Comment: I have not done anything to the JNLP configuration I am fairly new to it

As I said the JNLP is downloaded perfectly 

it shows me the first view in the UI which is a login page...

When I type in Username and password and click login it freezes after that

Comment: I can ping the ip and also i have the jar file on my machine using that jar I am able to make changes in the database that means the port 3306 is open right?
I am not sure, if the port were closed I think I wont be able access it using the jar file on other machine right?

Also I edited the question to add caused by is that the cause you are refferring to

Comment: could you guide me on signing my jar I would really appreciate that THanks for the effort +!